py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o41.saveAsTable. this error occurred while running below code
from pyspark.sql import *


if __name__ =="__main__":
    spark =SparkSession.builder.appName("helloSpark2").master("local[3]") \
             .enableHiveSupport() \
            .getOrCreate()

    df=spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true") \
        .option("inferSchema","true") \
        .load("data/annual.csv")

    spark.sql("create database IF NOT EXISTS SK_DATABASE")
    spark.catalog.setCurrentDatabase("SK_DATABASE")
    df.write.format("csv").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("annual_data_table")



Trying to save spark data frame as a have table, but constantly getting error I have Python 3.11 version and spark and PySpark 3.5 and py4j py4j-0.10.9.7-src.
Can anyone help why this error is coming:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Pycharmprojects\HelloSpark\create_table.py", line 16, in <module>
    df.write.format("csv").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("annual_data_table")
File "C:\Spark\spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py", line 1586, in saveAsTable
    self._jwrite.saveAsTable(name)
File "C:\Spark\spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
File "C:\Spark\spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py", line 179, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Spark\spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o41.saveAsTable.

